# How to read-in files (with underscores) using `pgfplotstabletypeset` in a loop?

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have a question on the use of the `pgfplotstabletypeset`.

I use it to read in tables with underscores and there I need to parse the strings in each cell (see code).

This works fine, if directly used in the code. However, it does not work, if it is wrapped in a `\newcommand`. However, it works if I use `savebox` (see code).

My problem is that I would like to loop over several files. This is why using `\newcommand` would be really good. For the `savebox` solution I do not know how to give the file name to the box (I have many files and therefore I would like to avoid to loop over each file). For the moment I have hard-coded the file-name for illustrating the problem.

I post below a file that shows the problem.

How to read-in files (with underscores) using `pgfplotstabletypeset` in a loop?

It works for tables without underscores, since then

```
     postproc cell content/.code={%

    \pgfplotsutilstrreplace{_}{\_}{##1}%
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\pgfplotsretval
  },
```

is not needed.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{a.txt}
 a_1 1 2
 a_2 3 4
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{b.txt}
 b1 5 6
 b2 7 8   
\end{filecontents}  

\def\Files{a.txt,b.txt}
\def\myfile{a.txt}

\newcommand\readtable[1]{
  \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    header=false,
    columns/0/.style={
    string type,
    postproc cell content/.code={%
     \pgfplotsutilstrreplace{_}{\_}{##1}%
     \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\pgfplotsretval
   },
  },  
 ]{#1}  
}

\newsavebox{\mytaba}
\begin{lrbox}{\mytaba}  
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
 header=false,
 columns/0/.style={
  string type,
  postproc cell content/.code={%
    \pgfplotsutilstrreplace{_}{\_}{##1}%
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\pgfplotsretval
  },
 },  
]{a.txt}
\end{lrbox}


\begin{document}

%
% first test pgfplotstabletypeset outside loops
%
print \myfile{} outside loop using pgfplotstabletypeset

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
 header=false,
 columns/0/.style={
  string type,
  postproc cell content/.code={%
    \pgfplotsutilstrreplace{_}{\_}{##1}%
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\pgfplotsretval
  },
 },  
]{\myfile}  

%
% now use wrapped command
%
print \myfile{} outside loop using readtable

\readtable{\myfile}

%
% Try with savebox
%
print \myfile{} outside loop using savebox

\usebox{\mytaba}

%
% test inside loop
%
\foreach [count=\xi] \x in \Files
{

 print in loop file \x

 \pgfplotstabletypeset[
   header=false,
   columns/0/.style={
   string type,
   postproc cell content/.code={%
     \pgfplotsutilstrreplace{_}{\_}{##1}%
     \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\pgfplotsretval
   },
  },  
 ]{\x}    
}

\end{document}
```

This is the output
[image]

I am working on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.34; using libpng 1.6.34
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with poppler version 0.62.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I could do it with wraping things in `\scantokens`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{a.txt}
 a_1 1 2
 a_2 3 4
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{b.txt}
 b1 5 6
 b2 7 8   
\end{filecontents}  

\def\Files{a.txt,b.txt}
\def\myfile{a.txt}

\newcommand\readtable[1]{
\scantokens{\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    header=false,
    columns/0/.style={
    string type,
    postproc cell content/.code={%
     \pgfplotsutilstrreplace{_}{\_}{##1}%
     \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\pgfplotsretval
   },
  },  
 ]{#1}  
}}

\newsavebox{\mytaba}
\newcommand\readtablesavebox[1]{
  \scantokens{\begin{lrbox}{\mytaba}  
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    header=false,
    columns/0/.style={
    string type,
    postproc cell content/.code={%
     \pgfplotsutilstrreplace{_}{\_}{##1}%
     \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\pgfplotsretval
   },
  },  
 ]{#1}  
\end{lrbox}}%
\usebox{\mytaba}
}

\begin{document}
%
% first test pgfplotstabletypeset outside loops
%
print \myfile{} outside loop using pgfplotstabletypeset

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
 header=false,
 columns/0/.style={
  string type,
  postproc cell content/.code={%
    \pgfplotsutilstrreplace{_}{\_}{##1}%
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\pgfplotsretval
  },
 },  
]{\myfile}  

%
% now use wrapped command
%
print \myfile{} outside loop using readtable

\readtable{\myfile}

%
% Try with savebox
%
print \myfile{} outside loop using readtablesavebox

\readtablesavebox{\myfile}

%
% test inside loop
%
\foreach [count=\xi] \x in \Files
{

 print in loop file \x

 \scantokens{\pgfplotstabletypeset[
   header=false,
   columns/0/.style={
   string type,
   postproc cell content/.code={%
     \pgfplotsutilstrreplace{_}{\_}{##1}%
     \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}\pgfplotsretval
   },
  },  
 ]{\x}    
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you.